# ReactJS: how do I receive form data from external application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, react-router, react-redux

I have a ReactJS app. The app submits a form to an external url. So what happens is that when the form is submitted, if an error occurs, the server at the external url sends the error message and status back to the app using a redirect url which was supplied within the form. So what I want is to be able to read the POST form data sent from the external app so I can at the very least display the error.
The problem I'm having is that when the external server redirects to the url I supplied, it shows "Cannot POST /" on an intercepted page. It doesn't even load the component on that page, and then it shows on the console "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) :8000/#/payment-confirmation"
Below is my Router:

```
import PaymentPreview from './payment-preview';
import PaymentConfirmation from './payment-confirmation';
      <Switch>
        ...
        <Route path='/payment-preview' component={PaymentPreview} />
        <Route path='/payment-confirmation' component={PaymentConfirmation} />
      </Switch>
```

This is the form I posted to the external URL

```
<form action="url-goes-here" method="POST" target="_blank">
                      <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="10" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="pay_item_id" value="20" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5000" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="599" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="site_redirect_url" value="http://localhost:8000/#/payment-confirmation" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="txn_ref" value="3834734873dshjhj3434" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="cust_id" value="5664" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="site_name" value="MySite" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="cust_name" value="Anietie Asuquo" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="hash" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="mac" value="mac" />
                      <RaisedButton
                        type="submit"
                        label="Confirm & Pay"
                        primary={false}
                        className="normal-case"
                        keyboardFocused={true}
                        backgroundColor="#E53935"
                        labelColor="#ffffff"
                        fullWidth={true}
                        // onTouchTap={this.formSubmit}
                      />
                    </form>
```

When I check chrome network tab I see the formData sent by the server, how do I grab and process them on my page? I need help please.

Comment: do you have a server running that can respond to post requests?

Comment: No I don't, should I? I mean I can create an Express server to do that, just that I thought I could read the POST data just as I would a GET url query.

Comment: Please do you have an idea of how I can make the Express server such that it runs alongside the React app and only handles post requests from the external url? Also how do I get the data it gets from the post request to the react app?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. Now it fixed

```
"site_redirect_url" should be https url
```

I can't fix it from my development environment. So am uploaded my project to test environment or production environment, then i convert my test or production domain url to `https`. finally it's works perfectly.